# Micronaut convert array of objects to json response in Controller method

Tags: micronaut

I have array of objects in Micronaut, want to return as `JSON` response of controller method. what is the best way of converting objects into json response.

In Groovy I do it like this array of server objects:

```
def generator = new JsonGenerator.Options()
        .excludeNulls()
        .dateFormat('yyyy@MM')
        .excludeFieldsByName('age', 'password')
        .excludeFieldsByType(URL)
        .build()

def output = JsonOutput.prettyPrint(generator.toJson(servers))
```

Same is not compiling in Micronaut project.

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Same is not compiling in Micronaut project.

I have pasted the code directly from the question above into a Micronaut app and it compiles fine.

Make sure you are using `groovy.json.JsonGenerator`, not `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator`.  `groovy.json.JsonGenerator` is in `'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json'`.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I switched to `groovy.json.JsonGenerator` now its working.